# Kafka Connect JDBC connector query + incrementing mode chokes with large datasets at initial poll

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using the JDBC connector to move data from MySQL into Kafka. The data I'm interested in is coming from a select joining 3 tables, therefore I've configured my connector with `mode:incrementing` and `query`:

```
{
    "name": "stats",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry.kafka-broker:8081",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry.kafka-broker:8081",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://DB_HOST:3306/SCHEMA?user=USER&password=PASSWORD&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&useSSL=false",
        "mode": "incrementing",
        "validate.non.null": "false",
        "topic.prefix": "t",
        "incrementing.column.name": "s.id",
        "transforms": "createKey,extractString",
        "transforms.createKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
        "transforms.createKey.fields": "uuid",
        "transforms.extractString.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
        "transforms.extractString.field": "uuid",
        "quote.sql.identifiers":"never",
        "query": "select s.id, concat(database(), '_', s.id) as uuid, c.email, s.type as type, s.created_at as log_date, a.type as a_type from stats s join concact c on c.id = s.recipient_id join address a on a.id = s.address_id",
        "errors.tolerance": "all",
        "errors.log.enable": "true",
        "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
        "batch.max.rows": "100",
        "poll.interval.ms": "60000"
    }
}
```

When checking the connector status I get that is running:

```
curl http://conncet:8083/connectors/stats/status

{
    "name": "stats",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "connect-3:38083"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "worker_id": "connect-1:18083"
        }
    ],
    "type": "source"
}
```

But after an hour I still don't see the topic created. I've checked in MySQL which queries are running with `show full processlist;` and I see two queries like this:

```
select s.id, concat(database(), '_', s.id) as uuid, c.email, s.type as type, s.created_at as log_date, a.type as a_type from stats s join concact c on c.id = s.recipient_id join address a on a.id = s.address_id WHERE s.id > -1 ORDER BY s.id ASC
```

So basically the query is the same as the query I provided in `query` in the connector configuration plus `WHERE s.id > -1 ORDER BY s.id ASC`, since the query in this join produces a resultset of 21 millon rows MySQL is sending the Data for a long time. When I check again with `show full processlist;` I see now 4 queries like this, and then 8, and then 16, and so on.

**The questions are:**

1. Why is Kafka connect trying to get **ALL** the rows at once when adding: `s.id > -1 ORDER BY s.id ASC`.
2. Is it possible to configure the connector to not do this, and instead fetch a smaller amount?
3. Is `"batch.max.rows": "100"` only controlling the batch size after the initial poll??

**Update:**

There is an open topic for this [issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/181). I think this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC Source Connector with `incrementing` `mode` and passed `query`, 
execute that query with following where clause: `WHERE incrementingColumnName > lastIncrementedValue ORDER BY incrementingColumnName ASC`.
(if you use incremental mode and query you can't pass `where` clause there).

At first poll `lastIncrementedValue` is -1, so it try to query all records. After extracting each records lastIncrementedValue increases, so next querying will only poll new data.
`batch.max.rows` refers to how many records `SourceTask::poll(...)` will return to Kafka Connect framework.
It is the max size of the batch that will be sent to Kafka at once.

I think, when you fetch data from single table it works faster, because the query executes faster (less complicated). 
If you execute those queries using other SQL tools it would perform similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not answering my question: Why is Kafka connect trying to get ALL the rows at once when adding: s.id > -1 ORDER BY s.id ASC. Which I think might now have an answer so I will reformulate. Thanks though

Answer (score 4):

query.suffix was added in 5.5.  I used it to add a limit statement and it worked great, it just appends the limit to the end of the query.

see [issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/pull/730)